# Share PPTP vpn connection to lan clients

Tags: debian, vpn, pptp

Server:

`enp11s0` - physical interface (inet 192.168.0.5)

`ppp12` - Raised VPN connection (inet 192.168.1.200)
The server does not receive an external IP from the VPN (this is how it should be)

But clients that connect to the server via GW 192.168.0.5 must receive an external IP from the VPN (ppp12)

Roughly speaking: In general, how to share a ppp12 connection with clients and give Internet access via VPN (in my case I want to let PS4 through VPN, because NAT3)?

P.S. Server must use vpn only for lan clients, not for itself.

Answer (score 0):

You want to configure "Split tunnel" routing for your VPN connection. The exact syntax for doing that depends on your OS and your VPN client/server.
If you have Ubuntu,then check out [this link](https://www.howtogeek.com/51340/setting-up-a-split-tunnel-vpn-pptp-client-on-ubuntu-10-04/).
If you have OpenWRT, then check out [this link](https://medium.com/@ingamedeo/openvpn-splittunneling-on-openwrt-e4302a1a4e12).

Comment: I have debian and i need setup this on console

Comment: Ubuntu is a Debian derivative.

Comment: Ok. I need setup this on console. On your link - gui

Comment: https://learningaboutcomputer.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-to-setup-vpn-pptp-server-on-debian.html

Comment: i not need "server", i need "Split tunnel".

Comment: On your link for https://medium.com/@ingamedeo/openvpn-splittunneling-on-openwrt-e4302a1a4e12

Comment: On this link, in script -  #Search route for traffic coming from 192.168.0.4/24 in table 'vpn' , but in script  `/sbin/ip rule add from 192.168.4.0/24 table vpn`, why ?

Comment: The basic premise is to direct default traffic to the WAN interface, and to only direct the traffic destined for the VPN network through the VPN interface.